# Where can I get in-car camera data?

Tags: data-request, images

I want to write an application which takes a single image an classifies each pixel as "street" or "not street". To do so, I need training / testing data. One possible application is for self-driving cars or car assistance systems. So the camera is within the car and looks at the street from a drivers perspective.

Where can I get such (preferably labeled) data?

(I have found [KITTI](http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/), but the site seems to be down at the moment and more data is always better.)

Answer (score 2):

You may do it a hard way. YouTube and other video hostings have a bunch of DVR videos that capture lots of real-world events.

### Find videos on YouTube

Say, by the Russians:

http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=russian+dvr

### Take random screenshots from these videos

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26850636/youtube-api-grab-screenshot-of-a-video-at-a-specific-time

### Label it with Amazon MTurk

https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome

Then do the analysis.

You can also ask data from authors who published on your issue and may have well-behaving datasets.